# chrome browser is not getting launched when selenium script is triggered from jenkins

Tags: macos, selenium, jenkins

Chrome browser is not getting launched when selenium script is triggered from jenkins. I have done jenkins setup on my local mac machine. Below is from the logs:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024}) on port 13498
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Aug 27, 2019 10:25:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
Tests run: 16, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 15, Time elapsed: 40.031 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

I have used maven and testng in my project. As per posted solution on other posts, I tried below but it did not helped:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo mv /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist /Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Comment: 1. This looks like selenium jar file not compatible with browser version
2. We have to provide executable permissions to this file
    Go to  chromedriver folder
     $  cd  ..\browserDrivers\chromeDriver\chromedriver
     $ chmod 777 ..\browserDrivers\chromeDriver\chromedriver
3. Run jenkins.exe using admin permissions

Comment: That file is checked in code. jenkins is pulling data from git where chromedriver is also checked in